# Postgres Left join between two identical tables very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I am having trouble understanding a performance issue.
I have two identical structured tables sensor_values and sensor_values_cleaned
The structure is

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_values
(
  ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  value double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NaN'::real,
  sensor_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT sensor_values_sensor_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id)
      REFERENCES sensors (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT timestamp_sensor_index UNIQUE (ts, sensor_id)
)
```

There are indexes of the ts and sensor_id fields of both tables.
(The tables are actually many partition tables split by yearly quarters)

The problem query is

```
SELECT MIN(s1.ts)::timestamptz(0) AS min_time, AVG(s1.value), AVG(s2.value)
FROM sensor_values s1 LEFT JOIN sensor_values_cleaned s2 USING (sensor_id,ts)
 WHERE s1.ts::timestamptz >= '2011-02-25T20:25:07.192132+00:00'::timestamptz AND s1.ts::timestamptz <= '2012-12-31T23:59:59.999999'::timestamp 
 AND s1.sensor_id IN (904 ) GROUP BY s1.ts::timestamptz ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

The idea is to get the original data and cleaned data for each sensor_id.
My original query does a pivot on this data but I have removed it as that part is not slow.

```
sensor_id 904 has 88000 rows in sensor_values and 0 in sensor_values_cleaned
```

This query takes ~1300 ms after multiple runs.
The problem is when I add to the IN clause

ie

```
SELECT MIN(s1.ts)::timestamptz(0) AS min_time, AVG(s1.value), AVG(s2.value)
FROM sensor_values s1 LEFT JOIN sensor_values_cleaned s2 USING (sensor_id,ts)
 WHERE s1.ts::timestamptz >= '2011-02-25T20:25:07.192132+00:00'::timestamptz AND s1.ts::timestamptz <= '2012-12-31T23:59:59.999999'::timestamp 
 AND s1.sensor_id IN (904, 967 ) GROUP BY s1.ts::timestamptz ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Takes 15 seconds with caching. On first run it took 40 !

```
sensor id 967 has 69600 rows in sensor_values and 0 in sensor_values_cleaned.
```

I have done a VACUUM ANALYZE

Any one know the issue or havd advice ?

Thanks

My query analyse is at

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189370/query_analyze.txt

Comment: Try creating a composite index on both tables on `sensor_id, ts`.

Comment: ... which can be UNIQUE, too (since {ts,sensor_id} is unique)

Comment: Post the childs' partition creation commands. It should not be scanning all children but just some quarters. The where clause must include the same criteria as the one used for the partition. Yes, the planner still isn't very smart when it comes to partitions.

Comment: The creation of one of the partition tables is at
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/189370/sensor_value_partition_table.txt

I used partitions to speed up access :( Do you think it would be worth while removing them ? The whole table would end up having hundreds of millions of rows.

Comment: Next time please use explain depesz for the explain output: http://explain.depesz.com/s/2aH

Comment: Sorry I did use that that but did not think to add the link here.

Comment: _Do you think it would be worth while removing them ?_ No! Partitions are exactly for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last cast in the following condition (`::timestamp`) may be taking away the planner's opportunity to restrict the tables to search in

```
WHERE 
    s1.ts::timestamptz >= '2011-02-25T20:25:07.192132+00:00'::timestamptz AND  
    s1.ts::timestamptz <= '2012-12-31T23:59:59.999999'::timestamp
```

Try changing it to

```
s1.ts >= '2011-02-25t20:25:07.192132+00:00'::timestamptz and 
s1.ts < '2013-01-01'::timestamptz
```

Then compare and post the new plan. Also there is no need to cast `ts` as it is already `timestamp with time zone`

### Update

This does not explain the behavior but may make it much faster:

```
select
    sensor_id,
    min(ts)::timestamptz(0) as min_time,
    avg(s1.value),
    avg(s2.value)
from
    (
        select ts, "value", sensor_id
        from sensor_values
        where
            ts >= '2011-02-25t20:25:07.192132+00:00'::timestamptz and ts < '2013-01-01'::timestamptz
            and sensor_id in (904)
    ) s1
    left join (
        select ts, "value", sensor_id
        from sensor_values_cleaned
        where
            ts >= '2011-02-25t20:25:07.192132+00:00'::timestamptz and ts < '2013-01-01'::timestamptz
            and sensor_id in (904)
    ) s2 using (sensor_id,ts)
group by sensor_id
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: No change i'm afraid. I have tried various combinations on the timestamp now. Still takes 30 seconds.

Someone on the Postgres mailinglist suggested it was because of feeding in the whole of table sensor_values_cleaned into the join and that and I should rewrite with a subquery. I don't buy as it still should not be taking 30 seconds.

Comment: I did rewrite with a union that takes a 1.5 seconds after caching.
Does not solve the mystery of why the join is so slow though.
I found a post about empty partition tables that has similar symptoms to my problem but the solution does not work for me.

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAOpcnr-xdAUq7+aeqOSYYK=HdOUY6L+H7dF=8O3qP+7Td9th1Q@mail.gmail.com

Thanks

Comment: I tried your query. Like my union all method it took about 1.5 seconds. (I had to remove the group by and aggregates as only 1 row was being returned).
Maybe left joins shouldn't be used like this ?
I was sure I have read left joins should be faster.
Thanks

Comment: @glennpierce: Where would you have read *that*? It always depends, but generally left joins are more likely to be *slower*.

Comment: Don't recall sorry. Oh well. I think the union and above code is acceptable. Partition are checked by constraint now. (A missing timestamptz on a time and sometimes me putting in a < 9999-1-0) check doh.